# SQL statement, Joins

Tags: sql, join

```
select userId, firstname, lastname, userVehicleId
from users
```

I want to make an inner join between `users` and `userVehicle`. This is what I have so far, can anyone help out?

Inner Join

```
select userId, firstname, lastname, userVehicleId
from users
inner join userVehicleId
on userVehicle
where users.userId = userVehicle.userVehicleId
```

Comment: You have tagged so Many variations of SQL.... which are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, may be you need this query?

```
select u.userId, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.userVehicleId
from users u
inner join userVehicle uv
on uv.id=u.id
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to get userId, firstname and lastname for users who have vehicles, right?

It can be something like this:

```
SELECT u.userId, u.firstname, u.lastname, uv.userVehicleId
FROM users u 
INNER JOIN userVehicle uv 
  ON u.userId=uv.userVehicleId
```

Please, provide structure for `users` and `userVehicle` tables to get more accurate answer.